# How can I tell macOS not to charge the battery but allow it to run with the power cord plugged in?

Tags: macos, battery, charging

After two years my MacBook Pro (2017, Touch Bar) has a battery that’s getting bloated. I can’t replace it or get help at the Apple Store.

Since I use it at home plugged in 99% of the time, I’d like to tell macOS to just ignore the battery, not charging it at all. If I had the special screwdriver I’d physically remove it.

Ideally I want a terminal command or manifest file that I can use that would leave the laptop at 0% charge all the time. If it were to become unplugged it would just cut off.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to remove that battery. Bloated batteries can catch fire or explode.

Comment: Seconded! A CHEMICAL REACTION is taking place inside that battery. Even if you somehow find a way to not charge it via software the chemical reaction will still be happening. That battery is **dangerous** It could catch on fire. Go to you tube and search for "laptop battery fire" for examples of what can happen.